# Help explaining an aspect of the continuity theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

A textbook I am using has an aspect in the proof of the continuity ( standard epsilon-delta method) theorem that I need assistance with. The first part of the proof proceeds as follows:
Suppose $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ in $dom(f)$ and consider a sequence $x_n$ in $dom(f)$ such that $x_n=x_0$. We need to prove $limf(x_n)=f(x_0)$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $x \in dom(f)$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$.

Since $limx_n=x_0$ (this was part of a definition stated earlier), there exists N so that

$n>N$ implies $|x_n-x_0|<\delta$.

It follows $n>N$ implies $|f(x_n)-f(x_0)<\epsilon$.
How does $n>N$ imply both values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read it this way:

1. $n > N$ implies $|x_n - x_0| < \delta$.
2. $|x_n - x_0| < \delta$ implies, *in turn*, that $|f(x_n) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.
3. Thus $n > N$ implies $|f(x_n) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.